# Im getting this error project_detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_slug' when trying to run my code

Tags: python, django-models

Im getting this error:

> `project_detail()` missing 1 required positional argument:
>   `project_slug` when trying to run my code

```
def project_list(request):
    return render(request, 'project-list.html')


def project_detail(request, project_slug):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project_slug)

if request.method == 'GET':
    category_list = Category.objects.filter(project=project)
    return render(request, 'project-detail.html',{'project':project, 'expense_list':project.expenses.all(), 'category_list':category_list})
elif request.method == 'POST':

    form = ExpenseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']
        category_name = form.cleaned_data['category']

        category = get_object_or_404(Category, project = project, name=category_name)

        Expense.objects.create(
            project=project,
            title=title,
            amount=amount,
            category=category
        ).save()

return HttpResponseRedirect(project_slug)
```

Comment: urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.project_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^add/$', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name="add"),
    url(r'^<slug:project_slug>/$', views.project_detail, name='detail'),
]

Comment: those are my urls

Comment: You used `path(..)` syntax with `url(..)`s. Change `url(..)` to `path(..)`.